# Why does my application not need msado15.dll?

Tags: c++, com

This program's stdafx.h is a little like this below.

```
// ...
#import "./lib/64/msado15.dll" rename("EOF", "EndOfFile") no_namespace
// ...
```

The program works okay and there are no problems.

I was curious about what would happen if I deleted msado15.dll.
So, I deleted it, and the program still works fine.

I assumed that why the program works without msado15.dll in the same directory must be the dll file is loaded somewhere else.

To make sure exactly where the dll is loaded, I used "Dependancy Walker", and I found out this program is not loading msado15.dll at all.

I would be glad if I could figure out what I'm missing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Dependency Walker* can only see static DLL dependencies (where there's a reference in the EXE's imports table). If a DLL is loaded at runtime via `LoadLibrary` (or by delay loading -- using `/delayload`), *Dependency Walker* will not be able to see this.

`#import` doesn't actually impose a static dependency on the DLL. It loads the COM typelibrary information from the DLL at compile time. This is transformed into C++ bindings for the COM classes and interfaces defined in the typelibrary. You can see these as `.tli` and `.tlh` files in your `Debug` or `Release` directory. You might be able to remove the DLL file, and -- as long as these files still exist -- VS might continue to build your project successfully.

Similarly, at runtime, since `#import` doesn't actually impose a static dependency on the DLL (that is: it won't add it to the imports table in the EXE), *Dependency Walker* will be unable to see this dependency.

At runtime, however, the EXE will call (indirectly) `LoadLibrary`, and (if the DLL is missing) this will cause a failure at runtime, which your program might deal with appropriately, or which might cause your program to crash.

Even with all that said, `#import` merely imports a COM typelibrary. The COM typelibrary defines the interfaces used in the COM objects, along with the `CLSID` values of those objects. In order to find the code that implements the COM objects, the `CLSID` values are resolved using the registry (in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID`. The code implementing the COM objects **may not actually be in the same binary as the original typelibrary**.

This means that the DLL may not even be required at runtime. I think that this is rare, however.

Moreover, the COM objects may be implemented as out-of-process objects (meaning that another EXE is loaded). In this case, all that's loaded into your process will be the proxy/stub DLL configured for the relevant interfaces. Often, these will be defined using the TLB (in which case, your `#import`-ed DLL will be loaded); but they may be implemented in a completely different DLL. Either way, the DLL will be loaded dynamically, which means that *Dependency Walker* won't see it.

To see which DLLs are loaded by the process, you will need something like SysInternals *Process Monitor* or *Process Explorer*.

Comment: By the way, on the second paragraph, you wrote "#import doesn't actually impose a runtime dependency on the DLL." Is that a typo? Did you mean to say "impose a static denpendency" rather than "impose a runtime dependency on the DLL" Just want to make sure as I'm not a native speaker. Thanks.

Comment: OK. It doesn't impose a static dependency. It might not impose a runtime dependency, depending on what's in the type library.